# Django REST Serializer and unique_together and from_native

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am having trouble using the `SlugRelatedField` to deserialize a field that is part of `unique_together` set.

To given an example, I have a Blog model which has a Title and an Author. 
The tuple of these uniquely identify a Blog (as in the Title is unique to a given Author, but not unique site wide). I want to look up the Blog from a message containing just these values.

In order to deserialize a message (i.e. `from_native`), the `SlugRelatedField` calls: `self.queryset.get(**{self.slug_field: data})` which will fail on the Title slug because it is not globally unique. This can be solved by providing a more limited queryset (ie one which contains just Blogs but that user), but I am not sure how/where is the best place to set this queryset in the Field (because I do not know the Author until I get to deserializing that field).

One idea would be to do my own deserialization of the Author in get_fields where I could then filter the queryset for Blog. This code is pretty ugly, likely results in deserialization of Author twice, and has issues when the Serializer is used for the list view (as opposed to the detail view).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the QuerySet for your field at runtime.

You can do this in the serialiser, something like:

```
class MyObjectSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    def get_fields(self, *args, **kwargs):
       fields = super(MyObjectSerializer, self).get_fields(*args, **kwargs)
       fields['slug'].queryset = MyObject.objects.filter(self.context['view'].request.user)
       return fields
```

Or in the view as:

```
def get_serializer(self):
    serializer = super(MyObjectView, self).get_serializer()
    serializer.fields['slug'].queryset = MyObject.objects.filter(self.request.user)
```

It's the same thing — you're setting the QuerySet on the slug field once you have a reference to the current user — it just depends on which is best for you.

I hope that helps.

Comment: What about if the Author is not the currently logged in user but is passed by username in the request?

Comment: Then think of some other way of identifying the author. If necessary do it by hand early in the request and add it to the serializer context

Comment: I think this can be done by subclassing the Serializer and then overriding `field_from_native`.

Comment: Is there any way to tell the browsable API to render a related slug field for a field that does not exist on the Model?