# Specific queryset in SlugRelatedField for DRF serializer

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I want to serialize multiple Objects. The have a SlugRelatedField to "Descriptors", which have unique names within one Project, but the same name can occure in different projects.

Using this line in my serializer:

```
row = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field="name",
queryset=Descriptor.objects.all() )
```

causes an error, because multiple Descriptors are returned. I need something like this:
`row = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field="name",
queryset=Descriptor.objects.filter(project=projectid))`

Upon validation this causes `NameError: name 'projectid' is not defined`.
Can i pass the `projectid` variable when calling the `is_valid` method so i can specifie the queryset?

Answer (score 0):

After further search i found a solution which seems to work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24437490/9088940).

What I did is I added this to the serializer:

```
def get_fields(self, *args, **kwargs):
   fields = super(CellCESaveSerializer, self).get_fields(*args, **kwargs)
   fields['row'].queryset = Descriptor.objects.filter(project=self.context['id'])
   return fields
```

and handed over the id of the project via context

```
serializer = CellCESaveSerializer(Cells,  data=data,many=True, context = {'id':id, 'descriptoridlist' : descriptoridlist}, partial=True)
```